# A calculus question of physics

Tags: calculus

I know this might be easy, but please don't judge because I'm in grade 10, and idk anything about calculus.

I was solving a physics question.

I need to do

$$\cfrac{d}{dx}\left[v \cfrac{dv}{dx}\right]$$

I went on the math derivative calculator site, and it shows me this:

[image]

What's this supposed to mean?

Can someone please help? I'll be grateful

sorry I forgot to add

$$v=\cfrac{v_0}{x_0}\cdot x - v_0$$

and I think $v_0,x_0$ are constants.

*btw its not of any test, I can assure you*

Comment: Use product rule...

Comment: User112196: In the given physics problem  is time $t$ also involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of a function is the instantaneous rate of change of the function.  In particular if that function is the velocity function of some object then the derivative is the **acceleration** function. It can be shown that the derivative of $f(t)= t^2$ is $2t$ and that if we have a function, f(t), of t then the derivative of $(f(t))^2$ is $2f(t)\frac{df}{dt}$.  What you have is $v\frac{dv}{dt}$ which is exactly that except without the "2".  You can, of course, get rid of a "2" by multiplying by "$\frac{1}{2}$" so $v\frac{dv}{dt}$ is very likely the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}v^2$.  Look familiar?  That is the "kinetic energy formula.  Taking the derivative of $v\frac{dv}{dt}$ means that you are taking the "derivativ of the derivative" (so "second derivative) of the kinetic energy function of some object.

I notice you have "x" rather than "t" but that doesn't really change anything!  The "product rule" that Wolgwang suggested says that the derivative of the product, u(x)v(x), is the derivative of u times the derivative of v plus u times v: $\frac{du}{dx}v+ u\frac{dv}{dx}$.  In particular the derivative of $v\frac{dv}{dx}$ is $\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)+ v\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}=$$ \frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+ \left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)^2$.

($\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is the "derivative of the derivative" or "second derivative".)

If you do not know anything about Calculus, where did you find this questio?

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! i was solving my physics textbook and found a question which involved such kind of working

Comment: A general rule:  you will learn the mathematics you need for **this** semester's physics course **next** semester!

Answer (score 1):

It is direct differentiation simplification where you need to deal with constants.. as a coefficient or with  an added term . (It is seen that you had tried to simplify).

$$  Let \;\frac{v_0}{x_0}= A, \text{a constant. We are given}\; v =A x + v_0 $$

$$  \frac{dv}{dx}= A$$

Differentiating

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left( v \; \frac{dv}{dx}\right)$$

$$ =\frac{d}{dx} \left( (Ax + v_0 ) \; A \right)$$

$$ =A^2= \left( \frac{v_0}{x_0} \right)^2. $$

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You should not use $a$ in this context. One is tempted to think of $a$ as the acceleration.

Comment: There is no time variable here to get confused with acceleration . Anyways,